# Missing preload-helper export in vite package when building Nuxt 3 app

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, vite, nuxtjs3

I'm creating an Nuxt 3 application and it works fine when i run `npm run dev`. Though when I want to build the app with `npm run build` I get this error:

```bash
[vite:resolve] Missing "./preload-helper" export in "vite" package
```

I'm using Nuxt version `3.0.0-rc.6`

**My package.json**

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "test:unit": "vitest --config ./vitest.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "~3.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "~2.0.0",
    "jsdom": "~20.0.0",
    "nuxt": "3.0.0-rc.6",
    "sass": "^1.53.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "vitest": "~0.18.0"
  }
}
```

**My nuxt.config.ts**

```js
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt';

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  autoImports: {
    dirs: [
      // Scan composables from nested directories
      'composables/**'
    ]
  },
  css: ["@/assets/styles/main.scss"],
  vite: {
      css: {
          preprocessorOptions: {
              scss: {
                additionalData: '@import "@/assets/styles/variables.scss";'
              }
          }
      }
  }
})
```

**My tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  // https://v3.nuxtjs.org/concepts/typescript
  "extends": "./.nuxt/tsconfig.json"
}
```

I've been looking for an answer for a while now in the documentation, Stackoverflow and Google - but I didn't come any closer to a solution.

Does anyone know what this error means and how I can fix it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Chcked this one? https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/2882

Answer (score 6):

Same Problem for me - in my case i had dependencies to vite 3.x.
For the moment set Vite version to 2.9.14 fixed my build problem.

Comment: It was indeed a problem with the version of vite. `@vitejs/plugin-vue 3.0.0` uses a conflicting version of `vite` - So for me downgrading that package resolved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the `vite-plugin-ssr` and following versions:

```
"@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.0.3",
"vite": "^3.0.7",
"vite-plugin-ssr": "^0.4.48"
```

Updating these resolved the problem:

```
"@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.2.0",
"vite": "^3.2.3",
```